# Webcam not working in browser

Tags: firefox, chrome, camera, lmde

Using LMDE4 on Aspire 5630-6091, with with 046d:0896 Logitech Orbicam (gspca_vc032x driver), the webcam works fine in softwares like cheese or guvcview. But it does not work when trying to use Firefox or Google Chrome in sites like Google Meet or webcamtests.com . Chrome does not even find the camera. Firefox, find the camera (webcamtests.com), lists it, but does not play (the message is shown: "AbortError: Starting video failed"). I allowed Firefox to use the camera when asked.

Comment: I had this problem but my second webcam worked fine on webcamtests.com but not on Google Meet, solved by changing the setting in Google Meet itself: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390875/firefox-wont-access-my-webcam-in-google-meet-will-access-it-for-other-sites/420539

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved with [the solution shared by javier.punche](https://community.jitsi.org/t/old-webcams-in-linux-gspca-drivers/38033).

After install the packages `v4l-conf v4l-utils v4l2ucp v4l2loopback-utils v4l2loopback-dkms`, it is necessary to launch the browser preceeded by `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so`

Example:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/chromium
```

It worked in Firefox too.